# Triple integral evaluation

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please explain how to evaluate this integral
$I = \int_{0}^{2} dx\int_{0}^{2+3x}dy\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}xdz$
the answer is 115. 
I thought you integrate it individually like $\int_{0}^{2}dx$ , $\int_{0}^{2+3x}dy$ and $\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}xdz$ and then multiply them together. This shouldn't result in a constant answer. Am I interpreting something wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you integrate
$$
 \int_{0}^{2} \mathrm dx\int_{0}^{2+3x}\mathrm  dy\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}x\mathrm dz
$$
individually and expect a constant? The bounds are variable dependent!

Move from the inside to the outside
$$
 \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2+3x}\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}x\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx= \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2+3x}z\vert_0^{2-y+3}x\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{2+3x}(2-y+3x)x \mathrm dy\mathrm dx=
\\\int_0^2\int_{0}^{2+3x}(2-y+3x)x \mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^2x(2y-\frac{y^2}{2}+3xy)\vert^{y=2+3x}_0\\
=\int_0^2x(4+6x-\frac{(2+3x)^2}{2}+3x(2+3x))\mathrm dx
$$
The rest is algebra and single variate calculus.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Your answer is right, but I don't see any problem with your first question: individual integrations give $2\cdot(2+3x)\cdot x(2-y+3)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think OP meant evaluate the integral in the $x$ variable simultaneously as well

Comment: I think he means like I did, which he tried as well (and which of course is not the right approach). This is quite doable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah yes, I realize you said exactly what I meant. Right, so what is unclear I am sorry

Comment: Your first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{2} dx\int_{0}^{2+3x}dy\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}xdz&= \int_{0}^{2} xdx\int_{0}^{2+3x}dy\int_{0}^{2-y+3x}dz
\\&=\int_{0}^{2} xdx\int_{0}^{2+3x}(2-y+3x)dy
\\&=\int_{0}^{2} xdx\left[2y-\frac{y^2}2+3xy\right]_{y=0}^{y=2+3x}
\\&=\int_{0}^{2} x\left(\frac{9 x^2}{2}+6 x+2\right)dx
\end{align}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: I find the answer is equal to $\color{red}{38}$.

Comment: Yes! the answer is 38. My bad. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: @Xstuds You are very welcome!